# Search multiple occurrences of a word from string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are storing a page HTML in one of the table column. Ex.

```
&lt;h3&gt;Introducing the Targus 2014 Educational Range....&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;span style="font-size: 12px;"&gt;Targus has launched its latest educational range. Please &lt;a href=""&gt;click here&lt;/a&gt; for more information. These products are now available for purchase from Dicker Data.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Think Outsid&lt;img src=";fileId=38" style="float: left; width: 176px; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" alt=""&gt;eOs Stowaway keyboard, distributed by Targus, is full-sized but folds to a size nearly as small as the Pocket PC itself. The keys are the same size as those on a standard keyboard, requiring little or no adjustment when using the folding keyboard. br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&amp;nbsp;Think Outside&amp;nbsp;S&lt;img fileId=39"
```

We have a word "FileID" which repeats multiple times in that string. "FileID" always has a values assigned to it(e.g) FileID=38, FileID=39.

I want to extract all the numbers that are assigned to this FileID. Intended Output
should have the resultset 38 and 39 for this string. I have tried with the query below but it gives only the first value. Any inputs will be helpful.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ArtContent, CHARINDEX('fileId', mycolumn)+7,2)  from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code checks only the first occurrence. If you want to search for more you need to

- declare a cursor.
- insert all ArtContent contetnt to it
- Fetch the first and get every fileId from it with a while loop until Charindex is -1
- Store the fileId in a temtable
- Fetch the next repeat
- Select from temptable.

Comment: Or write a table-valued-function and use `OUTER APPLY` to apply it to every row in the table.  *(Which I would do if I wasn't only on my phone.)*

Comment: I Like it. You should do this @user3441683

Answer (score 0):

Try this script.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (STRG VARCHAR (max)) 

INSERT INTO @A SELECT '&lt;h3&gt;Introducing the Targus 2014 Educational Range....&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;span style="font-size: 12px;"&gt;Targus has launched its latest educational range. Please &lt;a href=""&gt;click here&lt;/a&gt; for more information. These products are now available for purchase from Dicker Data.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Think Outsid&lt;img src=";fileId=38" style="float: left; width: 176px; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" alt=""&gt;eOs Stowaway keyboard, distributed by Targus, is full-sized but folds to a size nearly as small as the Pocket PC itself. The keys are the same size as those on a standard keyboard, requiring little or no adjustment when using the folding keyboard. br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&amp;nbsp;Think Outside&amp;nbsp;S&lt;img fileId=39"'

;WITH CTE(MOD_STR,STRG)

AS(

SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(MAX),SUBSTRING(STRG,CHARINDEX('FileID=',STRG)+7,2))
,CONVERT (VARCHAR(MAX),SUBSTRING(STRG,CHARINDEX('FileID=',STRG)+9,LEN(STRG)-CHARINDEX('FileID=',STRG))) FROM @A

UNION ALL

SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(MAX),MOD_STR +';'+SUBSTRING(STRG,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('FileID=',STRG)>1 THEN CHARINDEX('FileID=',STRG)+7 ELSE LEN(STRG) END,2))
,CONVERT (VARCHAR(MAX),SUBSTRING(STRG,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('FileID=',STRG)>1 THEN CHARINDEX('FileID=',STRG)+9 ELSE 0 END
,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('FileID=',STRG)>1 THEN LEN(STRG)-CHARINDEX('FileID=',STRG) ELSE 0 END))

FROM CTE WHERE CHARINDEX('FileID=',STRG)>1
)

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE ORDER BY LEN(STRG)ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

select --Leaddata,
*
from (SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Id,[value], LEAD([value],1) OVER (ORDER BY (select 1) ) LeadData
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str, ' ')
) TY
WHERE [Value]='"key":'